# vb.net code that will export / convert multiple selected files in to one pdf file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, merge, itext

I am trying to create a code that will convert multiple selected files to one pdf file . Currently the code exports the selected files in to a zip file. But I want to open all the selected files in one single pdf file .

For your assistance I am providing the code that exports all files into one zip file.

In the code below there are two table mentioned. one is document and another is vacancyapplication. In the document table all the files are stored  guid is the unique id in the document table.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports Ionic.Zip
Imports System.Linq
Imports NLog

Public Class download_bulk_cv : Implements IHttpHandler

Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim _logger As Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
    Dim vacancy = New Vacancy(context.Request("v"))
    context.Response.Clear()
    context.Response.ContentType ="application/zip"
    context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & vacancy.Title.Replace(" ", "_") & "_" & Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss") & ".zip")

    Dim files = New List(Of String)()
    For Each docPath As String In From row As DataRow In DB.GetData("select guid, originalfilename from document where id in (select candidatecvid from vacancyapplication where id in (" & context.Request("a").ToString() & "))").Rows Let guid = row.Item("guid").ToString() Select HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/documents") & "\" & Left(guid, 1) & "\" & Right(guid, 1) & "\" & guid & "." & System.IO.Path.GetExtension(row.Item("originalfilename")).ToLower().Substring(1)
        If File.Exists(docPath) Then
            files.Add(docPath)
            '_logger.Info(docPath)
        End If
    Next
    Using zip As New ZipFile()
        zip.AddFiles(files.ToArray(), "CVs") '.AddFile(docPath, "CVs")
        zip.AddEntry("info.txt", files.Count.ToString.ToString() & "CVs archived", Encoding.Default)
        zip.Save(context.Response.OutputStream)

    End Using

    context.Response.End()

End Sub
End Class
```

---

i have written the following code to merge the pdf documents  but its not working

---

Edited code

---

```
Public Class preview_bulk_cv : Implements IHttpHandler
''Implements IDisposable


Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim _logger As Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
    Dim vacancy = New Vacancy(context.Request("v"))

    Dim files = New List(Of String)()
    Dim sourceFiles = New List(Of String)()
    Dim directorypath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/documents") & "\download\" & Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd") & "\" & vacancy.Title.Replace(" ", "_") & "\"

    Dim pdf_document As iTextSharp.text.Document = Nothing
    Dim pdf_copier As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy = Nothing

    context.Response.Clear()
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & vacancy.Title.Replace(" ", "_") & "_" & Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss") & ".pdf")

    For Each docPath As String In From row As DataRow In DB.GetData("select guid, originalfilename from document where id in (select candidatecvid from vacancyapplication where id in (" & context.Request("a").ToString() & "))").Rows Let guid = row.Item("guid").ToString() Select HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/documents") & "\" & Left(guid, 1) & "\" & Right(guid, 1) & "\" & guid & "." & System.IO.Path.GetExtension(row.Item("originalfilename")).ToLower().Substring(1)

        Dim epath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/documents") & "\download\" & Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd") & "\" & vacancy.Title.Replace(" ", "_") & "\" & Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss") & ".pdf"
        Converter.ConvertDocument(docPath, epath)

        If File.Exists(epath) Then
            sourceFiles.Add(epath)
        End If

        If File.Exists(docPath) Then
            files.Add(docPath)
            '_logger.Info(docPath)
        End If
    Next

    Dim all_source_files As String() = sourceFiles.ToArray()


    Dim docs As PdfDocument() = New PdfDocument(all_source_files.Length - 1) {}

    For i As Integer = 0 To all_source_files.Length - 1

        Dim reader As New PdfReader(all_source_files(i))

     ' Using reader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(all_source_files(i))

        Dim finalpdf As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/documents") & "\download\" & Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd") & "\" & vacancy.Title.Replace(" ", "_") & "\finalcv.pdf"

        If i = 0 Then
            pdf_document = New iTextSharp.text.Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))
            pdf_copier = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy(pdf_document, New IO.FileStream(finalpdf, IO.FileMode.Create))
            pdf_document.Open()
        End If

        For page_num As Integer = 1 To reader.NumberOfPages
            pdf_copier.AddPage(pdf_copier.GetImportedPage(reader, page_num))
        Next

      ' End Using

    Next

    pdf_copier.Close()


End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

---

I am new with vb.net . I appreciate your kind assistance.

Comment: What have you tried as far as combining the PDFs? Have you looked into the iTextSharp library? [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) That can be used to combine multiple PDF files into one.

Comment: I have edited my question above. I have provided the code that converts single file into pdf. But i need to convert multiple (selected) files into one single pdf. I appreciate your kind assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of code to combine an array of PDFs into 1 merged PDF, it requires a reference to the iTextSharp dll I mentioned in my comment. If you can save each file individually to a PDF now, you can use something like System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(your_directory) to get the array of file names and then combine them with something like the code here:

```
    ' This requires a reference to the iTextSharp library (http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)
    Dim pdfs() As String ' all of your PDF files you'd like to merge
    Dim output_pdf As String ' the output file

    Dim pdf_document As iTextSharp.text.Document = Nothing
    Dim pdf_copier As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy = Nothing

    For i As Integer = 0 To pdfs.Length - 1
        Using pdf_reader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(pdfs(i))
            If i = 0 Then
                pdf_document = New iTextSharp.text.Document(pdf_reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))
                pdf_copier = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy(pdf_document, New IO.FileStream(output_pdf, IO.FileMode.Create))
                pdf_document.Open()
            End If

            For page_num As Integer = 1 To pdf_reader.NumberOfPages
                pdf_copier.AddPage(pdf_copier.GetImportedPage(pdf_reader, page_num))
            Next
        End Using
    Next

    pdf_copier.Close()
```

Comment: i am not able to implement Using pdf_reader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(pdfs(i)) statement. It showing an error to implement system.idisposable how can I implement idisposable in the present  download_bulk_cv class . I need to use the IHttpHandler .

Comment: Can you edit the code to show where you are trying to use the PdfReader? Do you have a reference to the DLL?

Comment: I have edited the question and provided the code... please have a look and assist me

Comment: Take out the line " Dim reader As New PdfReader(all_source_files(i)) " - the using block takes care of creating/disposing of the PdfReader.

Comment: Using reader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(all_source_files(i)) thisline shows an error staing "iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader must implement system.idisposable"  .. also no pdf is created. the updated code I provided in the question creates the document ... but its just taking the first file  x number of time (where x is number of file i have selected) and merging that same file....

Comment: You need to manually dispose / close your reader you've dimmed (the using block would have done this automatically) - Where you'd have the end using you need then "            pdf_reader.Dispose()
            pdf_reader.Close()"

Comment: can you explain a little... more... i am dumb.. and dont understand... can you provide edit in my code and provide it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for converting any documents to pdf files and merging them into one single pdf file

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="PDFMerge" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports Ionic.Zip
Imports System.Linq
Imports NLog
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions


Public Class PDFMerge : Implements IHttpHandler




Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim _logger As Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
    Dim vacancy = New Vacancy(context.Request("v"))

    Dim sourceFiles = New List(Of String)()


    For Each docPath As String In From row As DataRow In DB.GetData("database query").Rows Select HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Downloads") & "\" System.IO.Path.GetExtension(row.Item("originalfilename")).ToLower().Substring(1)


        Dim epath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Downloads") & "\" & Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd") & "\" & vacancy.Title.Replace(" ", "_") & "\" & Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss") & ".pdf"

        Converter.ConvertDocument(docPath, epath)

        If File.Exists(epath) Then
            sourceFiles.Add(epath)
        End If


    Next

    Dim OutputFileName As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Downloads") & "\" & Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd") & "\" & vacancy.Title.Replace(" ", "_") & "\" & vacancy.Title.Replace(" ", "_") & ".pdf"

    PDFMerge.MergeFiles(OutputFileName, sourceFiles.ToArray)
    Dim mPDFFile As FileStream = File.OpenRead(OutputFileName)
    Dim mPDFFileBuffer(mPDFFile.Length - 1) As Byte
    mPDFFile.Read(mPDFFileBuffer, 0, mPDFFileBuffer.Length)
    mPDFFile.Close()

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(OutputFileName)



    context.Response.Clear()
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & OutputFileName)

    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", mPDFFileBuffer.Length)
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(mPDFFileBuffer, 0, mPDFFileBuffer.Length)
    mPDFFileBuffer = Nothing
    context.Response.Flush()
    context.Response.End()



End Sub



Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

Public Shared Sub MergeFiles(destinationFile As String, sourceFiles As String())


    Try
        Dim f As Integer = 0
        Dim reader As New PdfReader(sourceFiles(f))     ' we create a reader for a certain document
        Dim n As Integer = reader.NumberOfPages         ' we retrieve the total number of pages

        'Console.WriteLine("There are " + n + " pages in the original file.");

        Dim document As New Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))              ' step 1: creation of a document-object
        Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.Create))              ' step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document
        document.Open()              ' step 3: we open the document

        Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent
        Dim page As PdfImportedPage
        Dim rotation As Integer

        ' step 4: we add content
        While f < sourceFiles.Length
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            While i < n
                i += 1
                document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i))
                document.NewPage()
                page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i)
                rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i)
                If rotation = 90 OrElse rotation = 270 Then
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, _
                     reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height)
                Else
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F, 0, _
                     0)
                    'Console.WriteLine("Processed page " + i);
                End If
            End While
            f += 1
            If f < sourceFiles.Length Then
                reader = New PdfReader(sourceFiles(f))
                ' we retrieve the total number of pages
                'Console.WriteLine("There are " + n + " pages in the original file.");
                n = reader.NumberOfPages
            End If
        End While
        ' step 5: we close the document
        document.Close()
    Catch e As Exception
        Dim strOb As String = e.Message
    End Try
End Sub

Public Function CountPageNo(strFileName As String) As Integer
    ' we create a reader for a certain document
    Dim reader As New PdfReader(strFileName)
    ' we retrieve the total number of pages
    Return reader.NumberOfPages
End Function


End Class
```

To convert the documents use a third party library like Apose Words for .net. Create a separate class as converter and a function ConvertDocument(ByRef docPath As String, ByRef expPath As String)  . If you already have all the files in pdf you dont need to convert them...

you only need to merge them

I hope this codes will help many people